# Are "maximum", "up to" and "at most" synonyms?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Do the following three sentences mean the same to you?

1: You may invite **a maximum of** 10 guests.

2: You may invite **up to** 10 guests.

3: You may invite 10 guests **at most**.

Are "maximum", "up to" and "at most" synonyms?

Comment: Are you asking "Do they have synonyms?" or "Are they synonyms?"  From your wording I can't tell.

Comment: Yes, in this usage, they are synonyms.  Each of these has other uses where they would not be synonymous.  You could also say, "You may invite **no more than** 10 guests."

Comment: Sorry, I want to ask Whether they are synonyms. @user3169

Comment: Thank you.@JasonPatterson  Is there any differences between "You may invite no more than 10 guests" and "You may not invite more than 10 guests "? Can "no more than" and "not more than" be interchanged?

Answer (score 3):

**In this context,** they are the same. They restrict you calling guests those are 10 or under 10.

> *a maximum* sets here the maximum number of the guests 
>  *up to* also talks about the number 10 as the maximum number of guests, and 
>  *at most* too sets the boundary of no more than 10 guests are to be invited.

Comment: a well-thought-out answer.